# Show a form on bottom right position of the screen

Tags: delphi

I noticed a strange issue in a Delphi 11.1 Windows application.

I need to show Form3 on the lower right of the screen after 5 minutes a button is clicked:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer2.Enabled := False;
        
  // Set form position on bottom right of the screen
  with Form3 do
  begin
  Top := Screen.Height - Form3.Height - GetTaskBar_Y_Bottom_Height();
  Left := Screen.Width - Form3.Width - GetTaskBar_X_Right_Width();
  end;
 
  // Now show the form
  Form3.Show;
end;
    
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer2.Enabled := True;
end;
```

It works fine and the Form3 is shown on the lower right of the screen... well, most of the time.

Because on some occasions, it is shown on the top left of the screen:

[image]

Even if Screen.Height and Screen.Width are correct:

```
Screen.Height = 1080
Screen.Width = 1920
```

Do you have any suggestion what can be?

Some additional details:

- I am using a single monitor with 1920 x 1080 resolution.
- The manifest of the application uses "Per Monitor v2".

Comment: What do the two functions `GetTaskBar_...` look like?

Comment: Why on earth so you use `with` here - you have actually _increased_ the amount of typing!
`Form3.Top := Screen.Height - Form3.Height - GetTaskBar_Y_Bottom_Height();`
`Form3.Left := Screen.Width - Form3.Width - GetTaskBar_X_Right_Width();`

Comment: Also, the TForm3 positioning code belongs in TForm3, not TForm1.Timer2Time. Should just add a `MoveToBottomRight` public method to TForm3

Comment: Why are you not using [TScreen.WorkAreaRect](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.WorkAreaRect) to get usable work space where you can position other windows without covering a taskbar or any shown toolbars.

Comment: @TomBrunberg the GetTaskBar_Y_Bottom_Height is used to get the height of the taskbar if it is on bottom (abd.uEdge = ABE_BOTTOM) using SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, abd) and then abd.rc.Height, the other one is used to get the width of the taskbar if it is on right (abd.uEdge = ABE_RIGHT)

Comment: @GerryColl The Form3.Top result is correct because: (Screen.Height = 1080) - (Form3.Height = 309) - (GetTaskBar_Y_Bottom_Height = 40) = 731 that is the same result I get from using Screen.WorkAreaRect.Bottom - Height. The Form3.Left is correct too compared to Screen.WorkAreaRect.Right - Width.

Comment: Ok @user2972081, I asked mainly to see if there was any error in your implementation that would explain the irregularities that you experienced. The `Screen.WorkAreaRect` solution in my answer covers all taskbar placements and size variations.

Comment: @GerryColl Ohhh, I get now, sorry, I forgot to write that the Height and Width had Form3. before, I corrected the code in the question.

Comment: @user2972081: FWIW, the change in your code has no effect. But all this highlights the fact that `with` should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did not yet respond to my request for the `GetTaskBar...` functions, we can just ditch them and use a better method to assess the available work area.

Also, you do not account for the position of the taskbar. Many, if not most, users let it stay on the bottom, but users may prefer to keep it at left, at top or at right edge of the monitor.

To account for the different layouts, you can use something like this `OnShow` event of `Form3`:

```
procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Left := Screen.WorkAreaRect.Right - Width;
  Top := Screen.WorkAreaRect.Bottom - Height;
end;
```

And you would call it from the timer event in `Form1`

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer2.Enabled := False;
  Form3.Show;
end;
```